# How to install and Configure Varnish in Magento 2?

Tags: cache, varnish, magento2.2.6

How to configure varnish in magento 2?

Selecting Varnish Cache in Stores Configuration is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting Varnish Cache in Stores Configuration is not enough. You also need to install Varnish on your server. You can refer to the following link to install Varnish with Apache on Ubuntu.

https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-varnish-apache-ubuntu/

After successfully installed Varnish Cache, you can configure it from magento admin configuration `STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > System > Full Page Cache.`

Answer (score 3):

Please check with below step :

```
Log in to the Magento Admin as an administrator.

Click STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > System > Full Page Cache.

From the Caching Application list, click Varnish Caching.

Enter a value in the TTL for public content field.

Expand Varnish Configuration and enter the following information:

Click Save Config.
```

Comment: Thanks, Its working for me. :)

Comment: @AnasMansuri its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

I follow this tutorial and successfully setup Varnish on nginx for my Magento 2 website

Reference source for full tutorial: https://magentip.com/install-and-configure-varnish-cache-magento-2/

**Step 1: Install Varnish**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install varnish
```

**Step 2: Configure webserver for Varnish**

**Step 3: Configure Magento 2 to work with Varnish**

Go to **Store > Setting > Configuration > Advanced > System** and deselect use system value and choose Varnish as Caching application
Step 4: Check if Varnish is working properly
curl -IL http://yourwebsite.com/